# Error while linking mex files in Max-flow/min-cut algorithm

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, mex, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement "Object Segmentation technique based on GrabCut" approach in MATLAB. For minimizing the Markov Random Fields Energy Function, I am using the standard Max-flow/min-cut algorithm as provided here: http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/code/

Question: When I try to create a mex file to call the functions of Graph creation and minimization in MATLAB, I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols:
>     "Graph::Graph(int, int, void (*)(char*))", referenced from:
>         _mexFunction in GraphTest.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> mex: link of ' "GraphTest.mexmaci64"' failed.

My code is really really simple, and just copied a part of the code mentioned in the README file as follows:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "graph.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{    
    typedef Graph<int, int, int> GraphType;
  GraphType *g = new GraphType(/*estimated # of nodes*/ 2, /*estimated # of edges*/1); 
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone who has used this package before or experienced similar sort of an error, could provide some insights into the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What compiler/linker do you use? Can you provide the command you use to compile/link? Besides, do you compile and link to `Graph.cpp` (or any other file where this class is implemented)?

Comment: Thanks Itamar. I was just compiling using "mex GraphTest.cpp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're compiling with Matlab?

Try:

mex GraphTest.cpp graph.cpp

I presume your mex gateway file is GraphTest.cpp. Any dependencies you can just tag onto the end. This works reasonably well for simple projects. When it gets larger, you'll want to switch to an actual build system w/ dependency. I prefer CMake.

Comment: Thanks pxu.. It worked! I was initially compiling
 using only "mex GraphTest.cpp"